# Viewing users in windows group

Tags: windows-10, users, properties

When right clicking on a file and selecting 'properties' 'security' then it shows a list of users and
groups. Namely my account; 'administrator' group account; 'Everyone' group account and 'SYSTEM' group account. My understanding is that the system; administrator and everyone account are generic windows group.

So how will I go about viewing the users in the Administrator, Everyone and System account without administrative rights on my machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a non domain setup.

If you're running a non home version of windows you can run click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type **lusrmgr.msc**, Click on groups and double clicking on any group will show you the members of that group.

Otherwise this powershell script will show you what you what for the **Administrators** group.

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"
```

**Output**

```
ObjectClass Name                    PrincipalSource
----------- ----------------------  ---------------
User        CONTOSOPC\Administrator Local
User        CONTOSOPC\LocalAdmin    Local
```

You wont be able to use this for Everyone or System but here is an outline of whos in these groups.

**Everyone** encompasses all users who have logged in with a password as well as built-in, non-password protected accounts such as Guest and LOCAL_SERVICE.

**System** is used by the operating system and by services that run under Windows. There are many services and processes in the Windows operating system that need the capability to sign in internally, such as during a Windows installation. Users can not be added to this group